# Existe alternativa para vários loops whiles?

Tags: java, estilo-de-codificação, while

Possuo um método `alterar()` que alterar os dados de um determinado elemento do meu XML Pessoa, entretanto, esta rotina usa vários `while`s um para cada elemento, veja abaixo a rotina:

```
public void alterar() {                 
    try {
        Document doc = parse(arquivo);                        
        
        List<Node> nos = doc.selectNodes("//pessoas/pessoa[idpessoa='" + String.valueOf(idPessoa) + "']");
        
        for (Node no: nos) {
            Element elemPessoa = (Element) no;
            
            Iterator<Element> itrIdPessoa = elemPessoa.elementIterator("idpessoa");
            
            while (itrIdPessoa.hasNext()) { 
                Element elemIdPessoa = (Element) itrIdPessoa.next();
                elemIdPessoa.setText(String.valueOf(idPessoa));
            }
            
            Iterator<Element> itrNome = elemPessoa.elementIterator("nome");
            
            while (itrNome.hasNext()) { 
                Element elemNome = (Element) itrNome.next();
                elemNome.setText(nome);
            }
            
            Iterator<Element> itrEmail = elemPessoa.elementIterator("email");
            
            while (itrEmail.hasNext()) { 
                Element elemEmail = (Element) itrEmail.next();
                elemEmail.setText(email);
            }
            
            Iterator<Element> itrCelular = elemPessoa.elementIterator("celular");
                            
            while (itrCelular.hasNext()) { 
                Element elemCelular = (Element) itrCelular.next();
                elemCelular.setText(celular);
            }
        }
                    
        escrever(doc, arquivo);
    }                 
    catch (DocumentException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }        
    catch (NoClassDefFoundError ex) { 
        System.err.println("Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Esta é a estrutura do arquivo XML Pessoa:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pessoas>
   <pessoa>
      <idpessoa>2</idpessoa>
      <nome>Marcielli teste</nome>
      <email>mah@mail.com</email>
      <celular>88888888</celular>
   </pessoa>
   <pessoa>
      <idpessoa>3</idpessoa>
      <nome>Ana</nome>
      <email>ana@mail.com</email>
      <celular>1233121</celular>
   </pessoa>
</pessoas>
```

---

## Dúvida

Eu gostaria de saber se possível, se existe alguma alternativa para todos esses `while`s?

PS: *Estou usando a biblioteca dom4j para processar e ler o arquivo XML*.

Comment: Por exemplo: `Iterator<Element> itrIdPessoa = elemPessoa.elementIterator("idpessoa");` ele retorna aqui quantos itens? porque cada `no` é um item desse XML?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic ai retorna um teoricamente, o `no` no casso pode considerar a tag `pessoa`.

Comment: Pra mim @DenerCarvalho são interações desnecessária acredito que tudo esteja ali...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tudo que existe um certo padrão é possível abstrair e tornar o código genérico. Então é possível criar um método que faça esse código de forma genérica "preenchendo as lacunas" que são especializadas. Exemplo (não necessariamente o melhor):

```
private void FillElements(Node no, String nomeNo, String valor) {
    Element elemPessoa = (Element)no;
    Iterator<Element> iterador = elemPessoa.elementIterator(nomeNo);
    while (iterador.hasNext()) { 
        Element elemento = (Element)iterador.next();
        elemento.setText(valor);
    }
}
```

Usando:

```
FillElements(no, "idpessoa", String.valueOf(idPessoa)) //preenche as lacunas
FillElements(no, "nome", nome)
FillElements(no, "email", email)
FillElements(no, "celular", celular)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/FillXml.java).

Não estou entrando no mérito se o código está correto e faz o desejado ou se está bem escrito e poderia ser melhor, até por não saber o contexto completo, só estou mostrando como generalizar o código postado e evitar repetição.

Isso pode ser considerado [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).